# requestAudioFocus for different API versions

Tags: java, android

I was trying to implement below construction for different APIs. I got an error message from a Gradle, that my minimum API is 15 and I could not build the app. What should I do? Where is my mistake?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   mAudioFocus = mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener,
           AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);
} else {
    AudioAttributes mPlaybackAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
        .build();
    AudioFocusRequest mFocusRequest = new AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN)
        .setAudioAttributes(mPlaybackAttributes)
        .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
        .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(mMyFocusListener, mMyHandler)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a plus to have your whole error message pasted here so we could have an idea what is the real problem.

So from what you provided, it might be caused by the minSdkVersion defined in the `build.gradle` , make sure it at least meet the API level your code needed because even though you defined, as shown above, your gradle still need to 'sync' with the same level.

Remark: different API level supports different Android architecture.